# factor( ) for multidimensional data structure in R

Tags: r

Here is an example:

A matrix like

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    3    2
[4,]    4    1
[5,]    1    4
[6,]    2    3
[7,]    3    2
[8,]    4    1
```

And I wanna get the some levels like

```
(1,4) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1)
```

Is there any function available in R?

Comment: If you just give the code for rendering the matrix, that would make life a bit easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate your factor directly with the `interaction` function, for example :

```
R> d <- matrix(1:10, ncol=2)
R> d
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10
```

And then :

```
R> v <- interaction(d[,1],d[,2], drop=TRUE)
R> v
[1] 1.6  2.7  3.8  4.9  5.10
Levels: 1.6 2.7 3.8 4.9 5.10
R> class(v)
[1] "factor"
```

Answer (score 2):

probably it is easy way to concat the cols into characters:

```
> d <- matrix(c(1:4,1:4,4:1,4:1), ncol=2)
> factor(apply(d, 1, paste ,collapse=","))
[1] 1,4 2,3 3,2 4,1 1,4 2,3 3,2 4,1
Levels: 1,4 2,3 3,2 4,1
```

Comment: factor is not numeric, even if it looks like numeric. e.g., a<-factor(1:2); sum(a) cannot work. Then, it is better to show what you want to do with the factor. There must be other approaches.

Comment: sorry I got it wrong. Actually I need the factor still be multidimensional cos I need them for separated operations.

Comment: @kohske Why `apply`? `paste` is sufficient: `paste(d[,1],d[,2],sep=",")` (and much faster).

Comment: @Marek good point. it is because if the number of columns are more, then paste(d[,1], d[,2], d[,3], ........). I don't like this. but of course, you are right.

Comment: You're not being very clear. What do you mean by 'levels'? Do you mean 'vectors'? Do you want to loop over rows of the matrix? 'levels' means something in R, which is why people are talking about factors.

Comment: THX all,I got the way to handle my problem with @kohske's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively one can use `factor()` directly:

```
> d <- rbind(c(1,3),c(2,3),c(3,2),c(4,1),c(1,3))  
> factor(d[,1]):factor(d[,2])  
[1] 1:3 2:3 3:2 4:1 1:3  
Levels: 1:1 1:2 1:3 2:1 2:2 2:3 3:1 3:2 3:3 4:1 4:2 4:3
```